# Removing mold from grout in tiled shower

Tags: mold

I have cheked this [question's answers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/how-do-i-treat-mold-and-mildew-in-shower-grout).

I am a renter. The apartment is probably 15 yrs old since last remodel.

- Q1) Does bleach work better than hydrogen peroxide?
- Q2) I do not believe the mold is behind the tile, so should I apply a grout sealer after cleaning to prevent future occurrences?
- Q3) No window, just a fan. Should I use respirator and stay out of bathroom while bleach is sitting?

Any other advice?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1) Does bleach work better than hydrogen peroxide?

Yes.

> Q2) I do not believe the mold is behind the tile, so should I apply a grout sealer after cleaning to prevent future occurrences?

Shower mold is cosmetic and on the surface. It's not growing from behind the tiles. Grout sealer will not make a difference.

> Q3) No window, just a fan. Should I use respirator and stay out of
> bathroom while bleach is sitting?

No.